# When can we equate differentials?

Tags: derivatives, chemistry

If I have the expression as shown below:

$$ dq - p_{ext} dV = ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T} dV + ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T})_{V} dT$$

Can I say that:

$$ (\frac{ \partial U}{\partial V})_T = -P_{ext}$$

...by comparing differentials?

This is a commonly used relation in many thermodynamics textbook but I'm not sure how to mathematically justify this procedure.

---

For those who are not familiar with thermo, there is usually a local implicit relation between the temperature, volume and pressure quantites.